# differentiable norm in complex space with inner product

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $H$ a pre-hilbert complex space (complex space with inner product). Prove that $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|^2$ aren't differentiable (Fréchet) in $H$. I don't know how to use the fact that $H$ is a complex space. Does anyone know?

I already proved that for normed space the norm isn't differentiable in $x=0$. By contradiction, supose that the norm is differentiable in $x=0$. By definition, exists a bounded linear operator $T$ such that
$$
\|0+h\| = \|0\|+T(h)+e(h) \quad \mbox{and}\quad \|0-h\| = \|0\|+T(-h)+e(h).
$$
Hence, $\|h\|=e(h)$. Therefore, $\|\cdot\|$ isn't differentiable in $x=0$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes, I already proved without the fact that H is complex, in generall for normed space but I don't know how to use the fact that is complex

Comment: You could improve this question by showing what you've done so far.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ok. I add more information